# Azure DevOps yaml pipeline: configure Azure Artifacts "package" resource

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Scenario:

- configure an Azure DevOps yaml deployment pipeline for a front-end app
- the front-end resources are published to **Azure Artifacts** as an NPM package
- Azure DevOps pipeline promotes initial package to a number of stages

Approach:

- Alt. 1: explicit "Download Package" task to download npm package from Azure Artifacts feed

```
      displayName: "Artifacts - download"
      inputs:
        packageType: 'npm'
        feed: '38a52be4-9352-453e-af97-5c3b448652f0/38a52be4-9352-453e-af97-5c3b448652f0'
        view: '070e33c7-f5c8-4561-8186-5c3b448652f0'
        definition: '1f32cfbf-1427-4b27-8476-5c3b448652f0'
        version: '1.0.1'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

This sort of works, but it requires either to specify a hard-coded version inside the yaml-definition or else a wildcard "*" (latest version).
Ideally, the version could be specified at runtime via the "Run Pipeline"-dialog. However, this requires for the package to be configured as a resource (Alt. 2)

- Alt. 2: specify a "package" resource on top of the yaml-definition.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-packages), there are number of possible resources: pipelines, builds, repositories, containers, packages and webhooks.
In this case, "packages" resource seems approriate.

```
resources:
  packages:
    - package: contoso
      type: npm
      connection: pat-contoso
      name: yourname/contoso 
      version: 7.130.88 
      trigger: true
```

However, the docs are lacking, only providing one example for GitHub packages.

I can't find any example, specifically for an "Azure Artifacts" package.

**Who can share a working "package"-configuration, specifically for Azure Artifacts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) with your first option

```yaml
parameters:
- name: packageVersion
  displayName: Package version
  type: string
  default: '1.0.1'

trigger: none

jobs:
- job: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy
  steps:
  - task: DownloadPackage@1
    displayName: "Artifacts - download"
    inputs:
        packageType: 'npm'
        feed: '38a52be4-9352-453e-af97-5c3b448652f0/38a52be4-9352-453e-af97-5c3b448652f0'
        view: '070e33c7-f5c8-4561-8186-5c3b448652f0'
        definition: '1f32cfbf-1427-4b27-8476-5c3b448652f0'
        version: '${{ parameters.packageVersion }}'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

And I'm afraid that you won't be able to combine this with resource as it can't support any way of templates/variables/paramataers.

Answer (score 1):

As **Krzysztof** suggests, the [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) should work for `the version could be specified at runtime via the Run Pipeline -dialog`. And you may need to add `extract: false` if you want to download the package archive.

> I can't find any example, specifically for an "Azure Artifacts"
> package.

For now it's not supported for Azure Artifact Npm package, [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-packages) has stated that `Resources: packages` option is only for Nuget/Npm github packages.

Comment: do you happen to know if integration of Azure Artifacts as Resources for YAML pipelines is on the roadmap?

It seems like a natural thing to come (hopefully), as a similar integration exists for the classic Release pipelines already (where you can define an Azure artifacts feed as an input artifact and get a nice UI for selecting the specific artifact version).

Yes, using runtime parameters works, but you won't get a nice UI for choosing the latest published artifacts (you can only make it a text field or static dropdown list)

Comment: For choosing pipeline artifacts (when using the `pipelines` resource), you will already get a really nice UI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#manual-version-picker-for-resources-in-the-create-run-dialogue

Something similar to that for choosing artifacts from an Azure Artifacts feed would be sweeeeeet :)